# Stop or Delete Deployed AppEngine Service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gradle-plugin

## Issue

I deployed an AppEngine instance as a sample by following the [Using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle) documentation. I am looking to stop or delete the version that is deployed. However, I am unable to do so in the AppEngine dashboard as the **STOP** button is grayed out and says

> You can only stop versions that are manually scaled, basic scaled, or in the flexible environment.

[image]

When I deploy **Jar** apps I am able to stop running versions in the AppEngine dashboard, but cannot stop this version which was deployed via the command line `gradle appengineDeploy`.

## Attempted Solutions

1. [Delete the project](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/hello-world#clean-up) which is not an option since I have a Firebase project linked to the AppEngine project.
2. Stop the version.

**Command**: `gcloud app versions stop VERSIONS [appVersion]`

**Error**: `(gcloud.app.versions.stop) INVALID_ARGUMENT: serving status cannot be changed for Automatic Scaling versions`

3. Delete the service.

**Command**: `gcloud app services delete service`

**Error**: `INVALID_ARGUMENT: The default service (module) cannot be deleted.`

Comment: *The default service (module) cannot be deleted* - this is the actual problem. *Something* must be running